# Caching Api Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

Would it benefit performance to cache recently used tokens for an api project?

My concern is to do a database query every request to validate a token would slow down a request.

Comment: Is the token user specific or all users use the same token?

Answer (score 2):

Caching in memory will always be faster than going to the database - BUT it's up to you to ensure that the token is still valid while cached. You could achieve this by only caching for a short time, or by periodically checking the database for changes to tokens in your cache.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I was leaning towards using cache for active tokens and having some sort of periodic function that removes expired tokens.